# Removing a subtring from beginning of a string in C

Tags: c, string, character, substring, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am having problems with removing a substring situated at the begining of another. I have tried 2 or 3 diffrent options but none of them seem to be working when I print the modified string. Can you tell me what I did wrong or tell me other ways to remove the substring?

Here is the code I used :

```
    int i;char *c,*p;
    c= malloc(200*sizeof(char));
    fgets(c,200,stdin);
    p=malloc(200*sizeof(char));;
    fgets(p,200,stdin);
    if (strstr(c,p) != NULL)
    { 
            if ((strlen(c)-strlen(p))>2)
            {
                  c= c+strlen(p);
                 //memmove(c,c+strlen(p),strlen(c)-strlen(p)+1);
            }
    }
    printf("%s \n",c);
```

Comment: and please mark question with a language tag (c and/or c++)

Comment: You should explain more carefully.  I think you are trying to remove the string entered in `p` if it appears at the start of the string entered in `c`.  If so, you need to remove the newline from `c`, you need an anchored comparison (probably `strncmp()`) for equality, and then copy the part of `p` that appears after the match of `c` to the start of `p` (so `memmove()` is correct and `memcpy()` would not be correct in general — more precisely, it is incorrect unless `p` is less than twice as long as `c`).

Comment: I found the problem , it was the fact that i was working with strstr

Answer (score 0):

You have to store/remember result of strstr() call, it is where your substring in a string is located

Your manipulation with strlen is useless, as far as I can see, and assigning to `c` is wrong because you're loosing pointer to heap string which is surely a memory leak

Update

something like

```
char* r = NULL; // result to be stored here
char* q = strstr(c, p);
if (q != NULL)
{
    r = malloc(200);
    strcpy(r, q);
}
if (r)
    printf("%s \n", r);

// cleanup
if (r)
    free(r);
free(c);
free(p);
```